# How to create a custom tag from hidden body in JSF?

Tags: jsf, custom-component, custom-tags

I want to create a security tag depending on the amount received, it will decide show or not, a body contents. I got it in JSP but I'm not getting in JSF.

In JSP, I create this code:

```
if (SessionControl.getUser().contaisPermission(role)){
    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}
else {
    return SKIP_BODY;
}
```

But in JSF, I don't know how to make hidden body. I tried to use `SKIP_BODY` but doesn't work in JSF custom tag because it uses `encodeBegin()` method and this method returns `void`, different from `doStartTag()` in JSP that returns `int`.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are looking for but it seems like you could use `rendered` attribute.

Comment: I created a custom tag, and i want a way for hidden body in this tag. I'll search for rendered

Comment: What is hidden body? Invisible element or conditional displaying in html page? If latter then `rendered` attribute should do.

Comment: What's the problem? Just do logically like `if (condition) encode()`.

Comment: My problem is, I wanted create custom tag that show or not show or body as the role attribute received, but a don't know how hidden body from tag. I wanted something like this:
       `if(user.getRole().equals(role)) {
           //show body tag}
       else{
          //hidden body tag
      }`